# "Could not install app. The tester does not have access to this app." error in TestFlight iOS app

Tags: ios, testing, ios8, app-store-connect, testflight

Has anyone encountered this error prompt message on TestFlight? I have used the current settings in my previous versions and builds that I have successfully installed on my device for testing (set code signing identity to my distribution profile and set my provisioning profile to my AppStore profile). My phone is running iOS 8.0.2 and my Apple ID is also set as a tester in iTunes Connect. I have also enabled testing on this version too in iTunes Connect. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't your provisioning profile release and code signing release be set to either an Enterprise profile or a provisioning profile that includes the testing device's UDID? It seems you're trying to code sign your ad-hoc build with an appstore distribution profile and wondering why your tester's device shows the could not install app alert.

Comment: I'm actually using the AppStore distribution profile because that's what worked before because the new process involves the build that you uploaded for testing will be also the one used for submitting to the AppStore.

Comment: Did you add this new user AFTER you already have a build on TestFlight? If so, you need to go into TestFlight website, choose that build, then find the "permission" menu. From there, you tick the check box for the new user, then hit the "update & notify" button or "just update" button. This will then allow the user to test it, assuming their test device's UDID was in the provisioning profile used to code sign that build of your app, otherwise, you'll need to regenerate a new build of the app with the newly added UDID and upload to TestFlight again.

Comment: Nope. I think you're talking about the old TestFlight from the site and not from iTunes Connect.

Comment: Damn Apple for not rebranding the service. (Same error here, previous builds worked fine.)

Comment: I think this is a bug already. I've done the same thing I did with my previous beta builds and it doesn't install. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I've been able to successfully get it to work is after activating the new version I have to uncheck the user from Internal Testers list, save, recheck the user and save again.  Then when I view the new build in TestFlight on the device I'm able to install it and no longer get the "Could not install" error message.

Comment: +1: Great, thanks, it worked for me! Has anyone filed this bug to Apple yet? I think I'll fire off a bug report for this when I have a free moment later...

Comment: Thanks gigq! It also worked for me. I'm currently filing a bug report regarding this.

Comment: @jaytrixz - What is the id number of that bug report? I just filed one and it'd be nice if I could let them know that ours are related.

Comment: @jaytrixz - The id of the bug I filed for the same issue is: 18543562.

Comment: @jaytrixz Apple says that they fixed this issue on October 9th.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare thanks for the update. I'll check and see if it's also fixed on my end.